# TouchableHighlight not working although using the source code from official react native documentation

Tags: react-native, touchablehighlight

I'm a new react native developer and I have an issue with TouchableHighlight where it always shows an error "Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child." in addition while I remove  it is work as usual and I assume if this issue come from my device/vscode/browser. Because I already follow the source code from https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight but still show that error.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptcds.png)
[Image without TouchableHighlight tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XWzb.png)

Here my code

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text>Touch Here</Text>
      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    <View style={[styles.countContainer]}>
      <Text style={[styles.countText]}>
        {this.state.count ? this.state.count : null}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);}
```

Comment: can you show us your code with a snack expo?

Comment: could you send us the exact code?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, the issue might happen if you pass Mutlipe child components to `TouchableHighlight`

From the docs:

> TouchableHighlight must have one child (not zero or more than one). If you wish to have several child components, wrap them in a View

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
  <View style={styles.button}> // Mutlipe child components are wrapped in a View
    <Text>Touch</Text> // component 1
    <Text>Here</Text> // component 2
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```